# JavaScript localstorage between multiple web apps?

Tags: javascript, ios, html, web-applications, local-storage

One of my web apps (for iOS) save something with javascript localstorage.

For some reason, I can access that data from that same web app, but not from another one, which is on the same website.

I really need to do this, so why doesn't it work?

And, more importantly, how can I fix it?

Comment: Do you see *any* other questions here with `Q:` in front of them?

Comment: In general the local storage is restricted not only by the hostname, but also by the protocol and port. is this all identical?

Comment: Yes, it's all the same... When i run it in Safari it even works !

Answer (score 2):

This is just a hack, you can use web messaging between apps to share localstorage data.

Resources you can find about web messaging

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage
- http://www.w3.org/TR/webmessaging/